# Exporting mongodb data into csv

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a real time application using node js and express and storing data in mongodb the data is getting stored every second , Now I want to add a frontend function where user can input the time stamp range (from this to this ) and after clicking the submit button a CSV file should be downloaded on his system with the data

I am trying to find the resources online but can't able to find any , if you can point out to me in right direction it would be great

( Data collection is done data is getting stored in mongodb )

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-to-csv

Comment: How do I integrate in to frontend my frontend is in express?